# Op-amps implementation

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, amplifier

I was asked to draw the implementation of three op-amps circuits and I am still learning op-amps from the beginning they have the following outputs \$ v_o(t) \$.

\$ 1 - v_o(t) = 3v_i(t) - 2 \$

[image]

**However I don't know where to input the potentiometer to gain the -2**

\$2 - v_o(t) = 5 v_i(t) +3 \int_0^t v_i(t) dt \$

[image]

**Also i wonder if this circuit is correct**

**3- A conditional circuit where we input a voltage varies from 2 to 7 volts gives out an output from 0 to 10 volts**

I know that t needs potentiometer but  i still don't understand how to use it

Comment: Are you sure for #1 the output is `vo(t) = 3vi(t) - 2` ? This requires the output to be shifted down by 2V. You can achieve this with a summer with one input tied to `-2V`

Comment: A summer of -2 volt like another input tied after the 2 ohm resistor?

Answer (score 1):

As @beccaboo mentions, this is possible with a single op-amp, and in this particular case, the numbers fall out nicely, making it relatively simple.  Where this circuit fails in practice will be its input impedance being set by the opamp itself rather than the resistor network.  Of course, the same concept would apply if we were to add a resistor divider on the V1 input and modify the rest of the resistor network...but now I'm rambling :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE5WmU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To the math, the key to finding op-amp gains is to remember that with negative feedback, there's a virtual short between the inputs.  That is, the opamp will do whatever it can to the output to make V- equal to V+.

Once that's understood, it is a matter of node analysis to find everything you need.  In the case of the drawing above, vi(t) is the sine wave connected to V+, with the DC offset provided by the DC source V2.  To solve the circuit, recall that the current through the feedback resistor (R2) must be the same as the curren through R1, as there should be negligible current flowing into the opamp itself.

Copy/paste an image from MS Word because I don't know how to write stylized math in this editor:

[image]

Now that we have a formula for now Vo relates to Vi, it is almost a matter of inspection to see that the ratio of R2/R1 should be 2 and V2 should be 1V to make the expression Vo=3*Vi-2 work.  I like simple resistances, so I chose R2 to be 2k and R1 to be 1k, but any 2:1 ratio will work, depending on other constraints in the circuit.

Cheers!

Comment: I guess I only answered #1.  @beccaboo is correct for #3, though I'd like to add that you're looking for something very similar to #1, with a gain of 2 and an input offset of 2.  So, it would help to start by writing that function:

vo = 2*(v(i) - 2), which expands to vo=2*v(i) - 4.  This can be also be solved with a single op-amp in the same way as #1, by changing the offset voltage V2 and the ratio of resistors.  The trick here was really realizing the formula that represents the relationship of the two range.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need the middle voltage follower opamp. For #1, something like below should give \$v_o(t) = 3v_i(t) - 2\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC6At4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you I see now i never thought of that, Do you know by any how if the 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud actually my circuit doesn't work. It's output is \$v_o(t) = \color{red}{-}3v_i(t)-2\$, but you want \$v_o(t) = \color{red}{+}3v_i(t)-2\$

Comment: We can make it work with a single opamp using non-inverting summer, but it will be complicated. I think it would be good to use 2 opamps to keep things simple...

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud updated the answer. It should work now..

Answer (score 0):

For #3, notice that the gain has to be 2 because 7-2 = 5 and 10-0 = 10.
You can shift the output with a summing circuit. Something like below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsGS1I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For part 2, one possible approach would be to consider each element of the desired function as an independent circuit.  Consider the formula as the following block diagram:

[image: Block diagram of desired function]

If an opamp is used to build each block, it is clear that we need a basic amplifier, an integrator, and a summer, so the circuit will be a bit more complicated:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKewb2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now to the math - using the same fundamental analysis used in previous answers, in which the opamp creates a virtual short between V+ and V- terminals, and those terminals are both infinite resistance:

[image: Math for previous circuit]

I hope that helps!